# Watir StaleElementReferenceError in form in frame

Tags: ruby, frame, watir, watir-webdriver

I am merely checking for the existing of an element on the page:

```
sleep 5 # for the page load
form.wait_until_present
next if form.span(:class => "SSSMSGWARNINGTEXT").exists?
```

`form` comes from these two lines:

```
browser.goto browser.frame(:name => "TargetContent").src
form = browser.form(:name => "win1")
```

Both the previous and the current page have `form` present, so I added a sleep to make sure that it had the new page. However, my program still crashes with the error:

```
[remote server] resource://fxdriver/modules/web_element_cache.js:5665:in `unknown': Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::StaleElementReferenceError)
from [remote server] file:///var/folders/80/_bwll9x91h7d6c5dp2d3fbb00000gr/T/webdriver-profile20120724-63693-194o52g/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:5354:in `unknown'
from [remote server] file:///var/folders/80/_bwll9x91h7d6c5dp2d3fbb00000gr/T/webdriver-profile20120724-63693-194o52g/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:6597:in `unknown'
from [remote server] file:///var/folders/80/_bwll9x91h7d6c5dp2d3fbb00000gr/T/webdriver-profile20120724-63693-194o52g/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:471:in `unknown'
from /Users/amosng/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:52:in `assert_ok'
from /Users/amosng/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:15:in `initialize'
from /Users/amosng/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `new'
from /Users/amosng/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `create_response'
from /Users/amosng/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:65:in `request'
from /Users/amosng/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:40:in `call'
from /Users/amosng/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:598:in `raw_execute'
from /Users/amosng/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:576:in `execute'
from /Users/amosng/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:542:in `find_element_by'
from /Users/amosng/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/search_context.rb:42:in `find_element'
from /Users/amosng/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.1/lib/watir-webdriver/locators/element_locator.rb:85:in `find_first_by_multiple'
from /Users/amosng/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.1/lib/watir-webdriver/locators/element_locator.rb:32:in `locate'
from /Users/amosng/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.1/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:384:in `locate'
from /Users/amosng/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.1/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:362:in `assert_exists'
from /Users/amosng/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.1/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:37:in `exists?'
from ./my-script.rb:123:in `foo'
```

What can possibly make it throw an error when I'm merely interested in knowing whether or not a certain element exists?

**EDIT**: So it seems like extending the wait time to 10 seconds fixes the problem. Since there is a bunch of Javascript on that page, I suppose the page might not have started reloading when `form.wait_until_present` is executed, and when `next if form.span(:class => "SSSMSGWARNINGTEXT").exists?` is executed, the form is no longer there in between loading pages. At least that is the only reason I can think of for this crash...

But the problem is, I have several places where the page reloads like this. Adding 10 second sleeps everywhere would slow it down to an unbearable crawl. How can I get the program to detect when a page has fully reloaded?

**EDIT 2**: Tried setting `form` every time page reloads:

```
    ...
    form = browser.form(:name => "win1")
    form.wait_until_present
    form.a(:id => "CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_SSR_PB_CLASS_SRCH").click
    form = browser.form(:name => "win1")
    form.wait_until_present
    form.input(:id => "#ICSave").click if form.input(:id => "#ICSave").exists?
    form = browser.form(:name => "win1")
    form.wait_until_present
    ...
```

Still a similar error:

```
[remote server] resource://fxdriver/modules/web_element_cache.js:5665:in `unknown': Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::StaleElementReferenceError)
    from [remote server] file:///var/folders/80/_bwll9x91h7d6c5dp2d3fbb00000gr/T/webdriver-profile20120725-47093-y3nzl8/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:5354:in `unknown'
    from [remote server] file:///var/folders/80/_bwll9x91h7d6c5dp2d3fbb00000gr/T/webdriver-profile20120725-47093-y3nzl8/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:6597:in `unknown'
    from [remote server] file:///var/folders/80/_bwll9x91h7d6c5dp2d3fbb00000gr/T/webdriver-profile20120725-47093-y3nzl8/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:471:in `unknown'
    from /Users/amosng/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:52:in `assert_ok'
    from /Users/amosng/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:15:in `initialize'
    from /Users/amosng/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `new'
    from /Users/amosng/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `create_response'
    from /Users/amosng/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:65:in `request'
    from /Users/amosng/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:40:in `call'
    from /Users/amosng/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:598:in `raw_execute'
    from /Users/amosng/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:576:in `execute'
    from /Users/amosng/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:542:in `find_element_by'
    from /Users/amosng/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/search_context.rb:42:in `find_element'
    from /Users/amosng/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.1/lib/watir-webdriver/locators/element_locator.rb:247:in `by_id'
    from /Users/amosng/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.1/lib/watir-webdriver/locators/element_locator.rb:26:in `locate'
    from /Users/amosng/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.1/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:384:in `locate'
    from /Users/amosng/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.1/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:362:in `assert_exists'
    from /Users/amosng/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.1/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:95:in `click'
    from my-script.rb:471:in `block (2 levels) in foo'
    ...
```

**EDIT 3**: Here's the test script in its entirety:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'

def foo
  browser = Watir::Browser.new
  browser.driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 3
  browser.goto "http://schedule.arizona.edu"
  browser.form(:name => "win1").select_list(:name => "CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_STRM$54$").option(:index => 2).select
  browser.goto browser.frame(:name => "TargetContent").src
  form = browser.form(:name => "win1")
  term_select_list = form.select_list(:name => "CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_STRM$54$")
  (1..browser.form(:name => "win1").select_list(:name => "CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_STRM$54$").options.count - 1).each do |term_index|
    (1..term_select_list.options.count - 1).each do |subj_index|
      term_select_list.option(:index => term_index).select
      sleep 1
      form.select_list(:name => "CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_SUBJECT$67$").option(:index => subj_index).select
      sleep 1
      form.checkbox(:id => "CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_SSR_OPEN_ONLY").click
      sleep 1
      form.a(:id => "CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_SSR_PB_CLASS_SRCH").click
      sleep 1
      form.input(:id => "#ICSave").click if form.input(:id => "#ICSave").exists?
      sleep 10
      form.wait_until_present
      next if form.span(:class => "SSSMSGWARNINGTEXT").exists?
      puts "got the form I want!!! do something with it: #{form.html[0..10]}"
      form.a(:id => "CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_SSR_PB_NEW_SEARCH").click
      sleep 1
      form.wait_until_present
    end
  end
  browser.close
  GC.start
end

foo
```

It takes until reaching ACCT to crash, but when it reaches ACCT, it crashes reliably (for me), though that is probably just because the 1 second sleep wasn't long enough.

The script with `form.wait_until_present` instead of arbitrary sleeps:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'

def foo
  browser = Watir::Browser.new
  browser.driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 3
  browser.goto "http://schedule.arizona.edu"
  browser.form(:name => "win1").select_list(:name => "CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_STRM$54$").option(:index => 2).select
  browser.goto browser.frame(:name => "TargetContent").src
  form = browser.form(:name => "win1")
  term_select_list = form.select_list(:name => "CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_STRM$54$")
  (1..browser.form(:name => "win1").select_list(:name => "CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_STRM$54$").options.count - 1).each do |term_index|
    (1..term_select_list.options.count - 1).each do |subj_index|
      term_select_list.option(:index => term_index).select
      form = browser.form(:name => "win1")
      form.wait_until_present
      form.select_list(:name => "CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_SUBJECT$67$").option(:index => subj_index).select
      form = browser.form(:name => "win1")
      form.wait_until_present
      form.checkbox(:id => "CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_SSR_OPEN_ONLY").click
      form = browser.form(:name => "win1")
      form.wait_until_present
      form.a(:id => "CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_SSR_PB_CLASS_SRCH").click
      form = browser.form(:name => "win1")
      form.wait_until_present
      form.input(:id => "#ICSave").click if form.input(:id => "#ICSave").exists?
      form = browser.form(:name => "win1")
      form.wait_until_present
      next if form.span(:class => "SSSMSGWARNINGTEXT").exists?
      puts "got the form I want!!! do something with it: #{form.html[0..10]}"
      form.a(:id => "CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_SSR_PB_NEW_SEARCH").click
      form = browser.form(:name => "win1")
      form.wait_until_present
    end
  end
  browser.close
  GC.start
end

foo
```

Crashes before even getting to ABE.

Comment: Since you are using `next`, does this mean that this code is within a loop? Are there any actions in that loop that cause the page or elements to reload?

Comment: @JustinKo yes, it's in a loop, and yes, there are many actions that cause the frame to reload. Which is my problem -- I want to wait until the frame has finished reloading.

Comment: Are you re-declaring `form = browser.form(:name => "win1")` each time the frame is reloaded? I usually see stale references when storing elements and then trying to use them after the page reloads without re-declaring.

Comment: @JustinKo aaah, no I'm not. I thought since it was the same form in the same location, it wouldn't matter, but I guess not. I'll try that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @JustinKo tried it just now, updated answer, still doesn't seem to work

Comment: I do not suppose this is a public page that you are testing? One thing you could do is wait for the elements you want to interact with rather than waiting for the form. For example, do `form.a(:id => "CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_SSR_PB_CLASS_SRCH").when_present.click`.

Comment: @JustinKo Problem is, sometimes I want to click things only if they happen to be present. The webpage I'm trying to scrape is http://schedule.arizona.edu/, and the page refreshes with nearly every click on every part of the form inside the frame.

Comment: Can please you provide a complete test script that reproduces your problem? I noticed/worked around a couple of the page's quirks, but I have yet to reproduce the same error you get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes it is better to wait for something to disappear rather for something to appear. In this case, when the ajax calls are made, you get a convenient logo that states the page is loading. Replacing all the `sleep 1` with the following got the script to complete without error.

```
browser.image(:id, 'processing').wait_while_present
```

The results seem a bit odd, but the following script no longer runs into the exception you were getting. Hopefully that helps you get going at least.

```
require 'watir-webdriver'

def foo
  browser = Watir::Browser.new
  browser.driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 3
  browser.goto "http://schedule.arizona.edu"
  browser.form(:name => "win1").select_list(:name => "CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_STRM$54$").option(:index => 2).select
  browser.goto browser.frame(:name => "TargetContent").src
  form = browser.form(:name => "win1")
  term_select_list = form.select_list(:name => "CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_STRM$54$")
  (1..browser.form(:name => "win1").select_list(:name => "CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_STRM$54$").options.count - 1).each do |term_index|
    (1..term_select_list.options.count - 1).each do |subj_index|
      term_select_list.option(:index => term_index).select
      browser.image(:id, 'processing').wait_while_present
      form.select_list(:name => "CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_SUBJECT$67$").option(:index => subj_index).select
      browser.image(:id, 'processing').wait_while_present
      form.checkbox(:id => "CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_SSR_OPEN_ONLY").click
      browser.image(:id, 'processing').wait_while_present
      form.a(:id => "CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_SSR_PB_CLASS_SRCH").click
      browser.image(:id, 'processing').wait_while_present
      form.input(:id => "#ICSave").click if form.input(:id => "#ICSave").exists?
      browser.image(:id, 'processing').wait_while_present
      form.wait_until_present
      next if form.span(:class => "SSSMSGWARNINGTEXT").exists?
      puts "got the form I want!!! do something with it: #{form.html[0..10]}"
      form.a(:id => "CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_SSR_PB_NEW_SEARCH").click
      browser.image(:id, 'processing').wait_while_present
      form.wait_until_present
    end
  end
  browser.close
  GC.start
end

foo
```